# Ubuntu 14.10 LTS 64 bit wont boot without live usb

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu from a live bootable usb after first trying it.  Now it is installed but wont boot if the usb is not plugged in.  Where did I go wrong and how do I move it to boot from the HDD instead of the usb?

Answer (score 0):

First boot the machine with USB, open the terminal and add the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr

sudo modprobe efivars

sudo efibootmgr
```

After this remove the USB and check whether the issue goes off.